# How to walk through a dependency graph?

Tags: python

I have tasks that need to be executed according to set of rules.

For example:

```
        | - File2
File1  -
        | - File3
```

Which means that the task of File1 must be executed before File2 and File3.
I wrote the following code :

```
import json
    json_string = """
    {
        "file1": {
            "path_to_file": "file1.txt",
            "children": "file2,file3"
        },
        "file2": {
            "path_to_file": "file2.txt",
            "children": ""
        },
        "file3": {
            "path_to_file": "a/file3.txt",
            "children": ""
    }
"""


class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, path_to_file=None):
        self.name = name
        self.path_to_file = path_to_file
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.append(obj)

    def dump(self):
        print('%s' % (self.name))
        for obj in self.children:
            obj.dump()

name2info = json.loads(json_string)

def get_tree(name):
    info = name2info[name]
    root = Node(name, info['path_to_file'])
    for child in info['children'].split(","):
        if child:
            root.add_child(get_tree(child))
    return root

root = get_tree('file1')
root.dump()
```

Which gives me:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

In this example the `print` is the `execution function` in the node.

The problem is that this code doesn't work for case like:

```
File1  -
        | - File3
File2  -
```

If I have:

```
   json_string = """
    {
        "file1": {
            "path_to_file": "file1.txt",
            "children": "file3"
        },
        "file2": {
            "path_to_file": "file2.txt",
            "children": "file3"
        },
        "file3": {
            "path_to_file": "a/file3.txt",
            "children": ""
    }
```

It will give me:

```
file1
file3
file2
```

It should be:

```
file1
file2
file3   #3 is child of 1 and 2 - it can be executed only after 1 & 2 are done.
```

Basicly each Node can do the execute function (print) only once all it's parents have completed their execute function (print).
How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you restructure your code so that instead of having links from the predecesor to the succesor you turn the relationships around so that the nodes have links to the tasks that should be execute before them?

Comment: So, that's not a tree, it's a graph. You can't model it with a tree.

Comment: Just a general comment: I think it might be a better design to specify things in terms of "parents" instead of "children".  That way when adding new child processes you only have to touch a single spot for the new child, rather than touching all potential parents.  The likelihood of forgetting to update a parent increases exponentially as the dependency graph becomes more complex.

Comment: Also, this is a fairly classic data science problem.  Depending on the features that you need, consider looking for an already established library to handle this pipelining for you.  For example, where I work we use [Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi).

Comment: @Ralf I can replace the children in the Json to parents. But how does it help me?

Comment: @0x5453 I'm familiar with luigi but it's too much for what I actually need. This is a simple question in graph theory (or I though as much) there has to be a simpler straight forward solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency tree isn't actually a tree - it's a DAG. When you print the tree at `file1`, `file2` should not be printed.

BTW you should not store the parent in the json, that will force your system to be a tree. (which may be fine, depending on your requirements)

Comment: The title says graph :) I wrote it as a tree since I didn't thought of the case I presented in the question. Obviously it require change of structure I just don't know how to create the new type so I can walk over it in the correct order of execution. It's OK to assume there is one root only.

Comment: Your code should work fine, can you be more specific about the issue?

Comment: I guess I;m after topological sort of the Json I have

Comment: Yup. You can use a library. Check out networkX: http://networkx.github.io/

Comment: I can't find an actual simple example which i can convert to my case. This lib seem more suited for more complex stuff

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you want is "topological sort": A list `L` of the elements of the graph, such that if `A` precedes `B` in `L`, then `A` is not a descendant of `B`. It's a standard graph problem; existing libraries should handle it. Here's [one](https://pypi.org/project/toposort/) of them.

Note that in a general DAG such an order is not always guaranteed to exist.

Comment: Should is the key. I can't find any compact well documented library.

Comment: I was using the wrong term! It's "topological sort". I've amended the comment and linked to a library (which I haven't tried).

Comment: I found it already. hasn't been updated since 2016 and there are 0 examples how to use it

Comment: Weak. Well then it looks like your options are to code topo sort yourself or use a foreign function interface.